# Java: Shuffle array elements within a 3d array

Tags: java, arrays, 3d

I have a multidimensional array I am using for a Java quiz application that contains the questions and answers (only showing snippet below).

```
public static String[][][] question = {
      {
        //question bank 1 (index 0)
        {"Question 1","Option 1","Option 2","Option 3","Option 4","Option 2"},
        {"Question 2","Option 1","Option 2","Option 3","Option 4","Option 3"},
      },
      {
        //question bank 2 (index 1)
        {"Question 1","Option 1","Option 2","Option 3","Option 4","Option 4"},
      }
    };
```

Within each array is index 0 (question), indexes 1-4 (options), index 5 (answer).

It'd call question[x][y][z], where x denotes question bank, y is question data and z the column.

When in a 2d array, collections.shuffle worked fine, but since I expanded it to a 3d array, this isn't working and I don't quite know what I need to change.

```
public void shuffleArray() {
    List<String[][]> asList;
    asList = Arrays.asList(question);
    Collections.shuffle(asList);
    question = asList.toArray(new String[0][0][0]);
}
```

Instead of shuffling, it randomly chooses either question[0] array or question[1] array content.

Ideally, i'd like to randomise the order of questions, as well as being able to randomise the order the options are displayed. For the first part at least, is there a simple adjustment to be made to collections.shuffle that can be adapted to suit a 3d array?

Comment: Right now, your code is *correctly* shuffling the *banks*. Is that not what you wanted? You haven't specified in the question what you really want (e.g. by showing example), but the code is working ok for shuffling banks, i.e. the outer-most array, sometimes returning bank 2 before bank 1, sometimes returning bank 1 before bank 2.

Comment: @Andreas I noted in the final paragraph the desire to randomise the questions and, in an ideal scenerio, index 1-4 in the inner-most array. So yes, it shuffles the outer-most arrays, which it did before, but this isn't desired in the 3d configuration. The suggestions noted are relevant to what I want to achieve, which I will be taking a look at (particularly about class utilisation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem up into smaller pieces and create an object for each row of each bank in order to get more control over how you shuffle.

1. Shuffle the options around in each row of each  bank
2. Shuffle the rows of each bank (questions) around in each bank
3. Shuffle the banks around too?

Consider the example below:

The original array is here.

```
private static String[][][] questionBanks = 
    { 
            {
                // bank 1
                { "Question 1", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 2" },
                { "Question 2", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 3" }, 
            },
            {
                // question bank 2 (index 1)
                { "Question 1", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 4" }, 
            } 
    };
```

The main method, which takes care of shuffling the array above, calling `shuffle()` and prints the result so you can see it.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    shuffle();
    print();
}
```

Iterate over the array of question banks and print each row of each bank.

```
private static void print() {
    for (String[][] bank : questionBanks) {
        System.out.println("==============");
        for (String[] row : bank) {
            System.out.println("------------");
            for (String el : row) {
                System.out.print(el);
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This method will shuffle the array by breaking it into pieces and using an object `QuestionBankRow` which handles the logic of shuffling the options and preserving the question / answer. By creating the `QuestionBankRow` object, you have more control if you have to refactor one day to add more fields or change the logic. If possible, consider using objects instead of a `String[][][]` array for your bank of questions as well.

```
private static void shuffle() {
    List<String[][]> banks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[][] bank : questionBanks) {
        List<String[]> shuffledBankRows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String[] bankRow : bank) {
            shuffledBankRows.add(new QuestionBankRow(bankRow).getShuffledBankRow()); 
        }
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledBankRows);
        banks.add(shuffledBankRows.toArray(new String[0][0]));
    }
    // if you don't want to shuffle the banks around, don't perform
    // this shuffle
    Collections.shuffle(banks);
    questionBanks = banks.toArray(new String[0][0][0]);
}
```

This class reads in a `String[]` row from the question bank, gets and shuffles the options. The `getShuffledBankRow()` method returns a `String[]` with index 0 as the question, indexes 1-4 as the shuffled options and index 5 as the answer.

```
private static class QuestionBankRow {

    private static final int QUESTION_INDEX = 0;

    private static final int OPTION_INDEX_START = 1;

    private static final int OPTION_INDEX_END = 4;

    private static final int ANSWER_INDEX = 5;

    private static final int NUM_ELEMENTS_ROW = 6;

    private final List<String> options;

    private final String question;

    private final String answer;

    public QuestionBankRow(String[] rowArr) {
        this.question = rowArr[QUESTION_INDEX];
        this.answer = rowArr[ANSWER_INDEX];
        this.options = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = OPTION_INDEX_START; i <= OPTION_INDEX_END; i++) {
            this.options.add(rowArr[i]);
        }
    }

    public String[] getShuffledBankRow() {
        List<String> shuffledOptions = new ArrayList<>(this.options);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledOptions);
        String[] shuffledRow = new String[NUM_ELEMENTS_ROW];
        shuffledRow[QUESTION_INDEX] = this.question;
        for (int i = OPTION_INDEX_START; i <= OPTION_INDEX_END; i++) {
            shuffledRow[i] = shuffledOptions.get(i - OPTION_INDEX_START);
        }
        shuffledRow[ANSWER_INDEX] = this.answer;
        return shuffledRow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, a `List<String[][]>` isn't a 3d array. It is a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of 2d arrays. So when you do a `Collections.shuffle(list)` you're only shuffling the order of the 2d arrays, not their content.

Imagine the List as a house, and the String[][] as their residents. With `Collections.shuffle(asList)` you're just shuffling the order of the houses, but their residents are still the same.

So to answer your question of:

> For the first part at least, is there a simple adjustment to be made to collections.shuffle that can be adapted to suit a 3d array?

No, because the [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface is only applied to objects like lists, queues deque and such. Not arrays! So Collections.shuffle won't work the way you want to on arrays. But fear not! There is a function that makes arrays behave like lists, [Arrays.asLists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_aslist.htm). You can do some research on it and see if it solves your issue, but I would strongly recommend you to use classes, it would be extremely cleaner and simpler! (even if you're a beginner).

Make a class for Answers, another one for Questions and yet another one for QuestionBank.

Your program will have a list of QuestionBank which will have a list of Questions and Questions will have a list of answers.

If you Collections.shuffle QuestionBank you'll randomize the order of questions, and if you randomize THAT question, you'll randomize the order of their answers.